# How can you derive that $\frac{x-x_n}{x_0 - x_n} c_{2d} \cdot x^2 + \frac{x-x_0}{x_n - x_0} c_{2f} \cdot x^2 = \frac{c_{2d} - c_{2f}}{x_0 - x_n} x^3$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How can you derive that $\frac{x-x_n}{x_0 - x_n} c_{2d} \cdot  x^2 + \frac{x-x_0}{x_n - x_0} c_{2f} \cdot  x^2 = \frac{c_{2d} - c_{2f}}{x_0 - x_n} x^3$?

Note that $x$ is a variable and the rest are constants!

Comment: How did you get those equalities? $(x-x_n)c_{2d} x^2 = (-x_n)c_{2d}x^3$ ?

Comment: Wait yes, that might actually be wrong! Should it be $x c_{2d} x^2 - x_n c_{2d} x_2 x^2$? In that case, I have no idea how I can derive the result that I want...

Comment: Are you provided with any condition that $c_{2d}x_n = c_{2f}x_0$? In that case you'll be having $(c_{2d}-c_{2f})x^3$ in the numerator